# gnuplot setting line titles by variables

Tags: gnuplot

Iam trying to plot multiple data lines with their titles in the key based on the variable which I am using as the index:

```
plot for [i=0:10] 'filename' index i u 2:7 w lines lw 2 t ' = '/(0.5*i)
```

However, it cannot seem to do this for a fractional multiple of i. Is there a way around this other than to set the title for each line separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sprintf` should provide all the functionality needed, e.g.,

```
plot for [i=0:10] .... t sprintf(" = %.1f", 0.5*i)
```

in order to use the value of `0.5*i` with 1 decimal digit...